# What happens to leftover money in the pot in Red Dog (card game)?

Tags: red-dog

In the card game "Red Dog", what happens to the money left in the pot after all the players bar one have quit the game? There can be a large amount in the pot that is not won.

I've looked at 5 sites which have the game's rules but none answer that question.

Comment: My understanding is Red Dog is a casino game is just one round played against against the dealer.  As any money if won or lost each round I'm not sure that you mean by 'the pot' in this game.  Unless your referring to another game of same name.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_dog_(card_game)